# Using Like + Order by + Limit in SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a query that will SELECT 2 columns for me, using LIKE, LIMIT and now I want to add ORDER BY to it because some bugs with the LIKE thingey.
I need it to ORDER BY the rows by a certain columns char length.
I tried doing:

```
SELECT `result`, `string` FROM `strings` WHERE `string` LIKE '%{$string}%' AND `approved`=1 LIMIT 0,1 ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(`string`) DESC
```

and it just gives me a PHP error while trying to fetch_array();
Using MySQLi :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `LIMIT` should be at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL is wrong it should be:

```
SELECT `result`, `string` FROM `strings` WHERE `string` LIKE '%{$string}%' AND `approved`=1 ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(`string`) DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Take a look at [mysql select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score 0):

See your result first using var_dump or print_r so that you can able to know why fetch_array gives error. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT TOP 2  `result`, `string` FROM `strings` WHERE `string` LIKE '%{$string}%' AND `approved`=1  ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(`string`) DESC
```